# Reported speech with conditional sentences

Tags: grammar

Could you guys please help me rewrite this sentence

He said: "if i had a permit, i could get a job"

Which one below do you think is correct:

• He said if he had a permit, he could get the job.

• He said if he had had a permit, he could have got the job.

Comment: Please take help in drafting the post. See also [ell.se] Good Luck.

Comment: How does conditionality make a difference?

Comment: If the original used *had*, why add *had had*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If properly edited, the question would be [He said, "If I had a permit, I could get a job."

Grammar rules support the second answer, but 'had had' (occurring twice together) may confuse. Let us make a comparative study:

He said, "If I studied well, I could score well. [Resembles to 'If I had a permit, I could get a job]

He said, if he had studied well, he could have scored well. [Resembles to 'If he had had a permit, he could have got a job.]
In the question OP has used 'have' as the main verb, which in past perfect becomes 'had had' like had studied.